# how to get Hbase meta data from Zookeeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I think there would be a lot of meta data were written into Zookeeper from Hbase, such as Region split info or Region and RegionServer info ect... But when I tried to get these information I got almost nothing, I tried each subfolder of /Hbase in Zookeeper via command get, but I just get a few lame data as following:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 40] get /hbase/meta-region-server
�regionserver:60020w��#�yPBUF
test008.tv.local�����Ч*
cZxid = 0xe0000018f
ctime = Mon Jan 25 10:39:58 PST 2016
mZxid = 0xe0000018f
mtime = Mon Jan 25 10:39:58 PST 2016
pZxid = 0xe0000018f
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 73
numChildren = 0
```

Is possible to get the full meta data about HBase in Zoookeeper, although there are binary, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This information is HBase's persistent storage of its current configuration.  It is not meant to be accessed directly, but by API.  This information is all contained in the [ClusterStatus](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/ClusterStatus.html) class, which can be obtained from an instance of the [Admin](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html) interface.  Programmatically, you can get this information with the following code.

*Imports so it is clear which classes are needed*

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
```

*Example:*

```
public ClusterStatus getClusterStatus(String zkConnectionInfo) throws IOException {
    /* this is the minimum configuration info */
    configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.set(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, zkConnectionInfo);
    // can be /hbase, /hbase-secure, etc
    configuration.set(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_ZNODE_PARENT, "/hbase");

    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration);
    Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
    return admin.getClusterStatus();
}
```

This is intended as an example.  It usually best to create the `Configuration` object from your site xml files.  For instance, this setup would not handle any kind of security configuration necessary for the cluster.

Comment: is there really no way to get these data by just command line please.

Comment: There's no supported way.  you can dive into the source code yourself and figure out how to interpret what is there -- I imagine it wouldn't be too hard.